# File upload in PHP and give permission for that files

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

I need develop a web app like www.Sharefile.com. I want users to upload and then give permissions to that file for access by particular users only.

I don't know how to give permissions for server files (upload file like pdf,word) using PHP.

Comment: Please add more details, such as the server'OS the web server and who are those users (system users?).

Comment: in development time i used XP and afterwords i hope to host some other place

Answer (score 0):

You ask a general question, so you get a general answer: I assume you already have some login set up for these users to upload their files.  Using this same login system, you can control permissions on specific files.  This is not necessarily done in php itself.  For example, user and file permissions may be stored in a DB.  The files themselves will probably have usual permissions.

Comment: yes, I have User login for users and save file access level in DB. now i don't know how to use this access level for download for files.